# PHP Disable round_up

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I disable the round up in my PHP script. If I sum up something it only displays the rounded Number.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM energrid WHERE ID = 1 ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wert = $row['Wert'];
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM energrid WHERE ID = 3 ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wert1 = $row['Wert'];
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo "here we go.:";
echo $wert + $wert1;
?>
```

Ok, I guess I've found my mistake. The values are like 3,5 with a , instead of a .

How can I change that if these are values directly from the MySQL DB.?

Comment: why are you using `while loop` if you are about to take just one record ?

Comment: 3,5 and -3,4 for example.

Comment: Do you mean `$wert1 = 3` and `$wert1 = 5` ?

Comment: rounded to what number ? Give sample input and output that you, inorder to provide better help

Comment: $wert1 = 3,5 & $wert = -3,4

Comment: was it `3.5` or `3,5` ?

Comment: Oh, yes. Forgot about the differents between , & .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can use [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function
2.**optimize your code** -there is no need of while loop to do this

```
 <?php    
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");  ///connect to mysql      
if (!$db) {      
// throw error if not connect      
 die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());      
        }          
$db_select = mysql_select_db("databasename",$db); ///select database      
if (!$db_select) {      
//database connection error      
die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());       
}      
$sum=0;       
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT sum(wert) as sum FROM energrid WHERE ID in ('1','3') ");       
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)       
$sum =$row['sum'];       
`enter code here`      

echo number_format($sum,'number','.','');
//where number-no. of  place you want to round off 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like this to replace the comma `,` in number by decimal point `.`

```
$a = "3,5";

str_replace(",",".",$a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cast like this :

```
echo (int)$wert + (int)$wert1;
echo (float)$wert + (float)$wert1;
```